# allow only access route when its nested RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-resources

I am new to RoR, and I am struggling with routes here. What I need is to allow my application GET routes like this:

```
root/trip/:id/destination
```

but deny routes like this:

```
root/destination
```

my route file looks like this:

```
resources :destinations
  resources :trips do
    resources :destinations
  end
  root to: "trips#index"
```

when I take out first row from routes than nested links break. What I am trying to accomplish is to start with

```
-> /root/trip(with linke to new file with new view) 
-> /root/show_all_destinations (with its own index and show action) and than 
-> /root/show_all_destination/:id (without edit/new/delete)
```

Comment: please read more about rouging http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html. It will help you a lot.

Comment: i am doing that, but i had other issues in my code. i solved it and now denying from root works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
resources :trips
  resources :destinations
end
```

If you do like above, it will deny `root/destination` but will allow `root/trip/:id/destination`

Comment: ok thank... that helped. now i cant access from root to destinations!